# Verifying IP address using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to validate an IP address. Following is the code. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong in the code?

```
import re

ip = '355.4'

m = re.match('^((?:1?\d{0,2}|2[0-4]\d{1}|25[0-5]).){3}(?:1?\d{0,2}|2[0-4]\d{1}|25[0-5])$', ip)
if m:
    print "correct"
    print m.groups()
else:
    print "wrong"
```

According to the IP given, it should print `wrong` as output but it prints `correct ('4',)` as the output.

Comment: Possibly interesting: if you want help debugging the regex, I've thrown it into [a visualizer](http://regexper.com/#%5E((%3F%3A1%3F%5Cd%7B0%2C2%7D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5Cd%7B1%7D%7C25%5B0-5%5D).)%7B3%7D(%3F%3A1%3F%5Cd%7B0%2C2%7D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5Cd%7B1%7D%7C25%5B0-5%5D)%24). It may be of help now, or in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a mistake by not giving `\` before `.` which was resulting in it matching any character.

```
import re

ip = '255.25.2.256'

m = re.match('^((?:1?\d{0,2}|2[0-4]\d{1}|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:1?\d{0,2}|2[0-4]\d{1}|25[0-5])$', ip)
if m:
    print "correct"
    print m.groups()
else:
    print "wrong"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to `not to use regex`, you can use python's socket package . `inet_aton("string")` converts the `string` to `ip` address,if this is not valid ip then it will throw exception.

Simple example I have tried:

```
    import socket

    def check_valid(address):
        try:
            socket.inet_aton(address)
            return address.count('.') == 3
        except socket.error:
            return False

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        print check_valid("192.168.1.255")
```

It will check all valid ip address like `192.168.1.257` is invalid while `192.168.1.255` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
len(ip.split(".")) == 4 and all(map(lambda o: o.isdigit() and int(o) <= 255, ip.split(".")))
```

Never ever use regexps in code. Please.

Comment: I wouldn't say "never", but certainly not for a problem such as this. +1

Comment: Why shouldn't I use regex?

Comment: because they are unreadable. it's write-only stuff. it's ok to use them in editor or in shell - for 1-time use (which I'm doing dozens times per day e.g.), but not in code.

Comment: @deceze I have yet to encounter problem where regexp is way to go :)

Comment: You should also not repeat yourself, you are splitting twice just to put it all into one line.

Comment: @iced, the is the point, not everything can or should be a single line of code. Also regex has it's uses in code so saying to never use it is simply wrong

Comment: show me single "proper" usage. I'd like to see one, really, but wasn't able to find anything in 17 years of my career.

Comment: `foo = re.match(r'foo(\d+)', val, re.I); if foo is not None: f(foo.group(1))` - Just wrote this the other day. Can you do the same in a more readable way without regexen?

Comment: if val.startswith("foo"): res = "".join(takewhile(lambda c: c.isdigit(), val[3:]))

Comment: @iced 1) Not *case insensitive*. 2) Does not check whether the value is *"foo" followed by a number*. 3) Arguably does not make it as obvious in a single statement what format `val` is expected to have. 4) The regex also allows arbitrary preceding and trailing characters here. – Yes, you *can* obviously do it without regexen, but sometimes regexen are the most concise way to do it.

Comment: 1. `if val.lower().startswith("foo")`, doesn't matter. 2. takewhile takes all digits after "foo", if there are no digits - empty string will be returned. 3. and yes, it's more readable than re. Don't get me wrong - I have no problem reading res, but lots of people can't read em.

Comment: @iced Your code is still missing the actual `if` check, in your case you'd need an extra `if len(res) > 0: f(res)` to do the same. It's also still not capturing from the middle of a string. In the end, it's *a lot more code* to do the same thing. And IMO, a little bit of regex should be a required skill for a programmer. `foo(\d+)` is universally understood, `lower().startswith()`, `val[3:]`, `takewhile` etc. is not.

Comment: it does capture middle of the string into res. regexps are not universally understood (less understood than common list manipulation primitives).

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the optionnal quantifier `?` in `:1?`.
Otherwise `....` is a valid ip address.